# Cannot use 'autoAttachChildProcesses' to debug forked processes

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I cannot **debug forked node processes**.

The forked process launches and behaves as expected; however, the debugger does not pause on breakpoints of the forked code.

Hovering over the breakpoint shows `Unverified breakpoint` tooltip. In addition, the Debug activity bar shows `Breakpoint set but not yet bound`:

[image]

I have 2 javascript files. The first forks the other:

**index.js**

```js
const child_process = require("child_process");
console.log(process.argv[0]);

process.execArgv.push('--debug=' + (40895));    
child_process.fork('./m1.js');
```

**m1.js**

```js
console.log(`from fork: ${process.argv[0]}`);
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "run.vscode",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js",
            "autoAttachChildProcesses": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using node `v10.16.0` and the issue is reproducible in vscode `1.36.0-insider` and in `1.34.0`; in Windows 10 or in WSL using the `Remote - WSL` extension.

Is the `autoAttachChildProcesses` property even supported for `child_process.fork()` or only for `cluster.fork()`?

Answer (score 1):

I made it work by passing the `--inspect-brk` flag through the `execArgv` option of the `fork()` method:

```js
child_process.fork('./m1.js', [], {execArgv:['--inspect-brk=40895']});
```

See more details in a corresponding issue I opened on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75253).